# How can I change an asp datapager's Pager.PagedControlID property at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, paging

This property was originally set in the aspx file, however I want to change it to select programatically on page load.

I set the Pager.PagedControlID property, but I receive the following error message on this line:

```
Pager.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ListLength);
```

**Page properties cannot be set because no IPageableItemContainer has been found.**

Any ideas? The ID I am using I copied and pasted out of the inline aspx and I checked it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

DataPager can work only with controls that implement [IPageableItemContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.ipageableitemcontainer.aspx) interface. If your control (that you wish to page) does not implement this property then you probably need to write a wrapper control that implements the interface.